# How do I fix a noisy input device (Internal Mic)? snd_hda_intel - debug included

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, debugging, intel

I'm having trouble with a very noisy audio input device - the internal mic or any plugged in mics.

So far I've narrowed it down to an problem in ALSA since my debug info is showing a lot of "null" values. Can anyone help?

Debug Info: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e0c6fb7e10624bf7691aa2b405cf0d3968e56c63

Exert from the debug:

```
model : (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)
```

Using Ubuntu 12.04 (x86_64)...

EDIT: For anyone still arriving to this looking for answers, the solution for me was to re-installing Ubuntu 12.04 and that solved the problem. Clearly something was wrong with the configuration when upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

The `(null)`s have nothing to do with this.

Try increasing the `Capture` volume instead of the `Mic Boost`.

However, it's possible that your analog input just is that bad.
Do you get better quality in Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using all sorts of configurations in alsamixer... non helped at all. Yes I do get better quality in Windows (much better!). Thought I'd see if it was just my internal mic, or not... so I went and grabbed out my old webcam w/ mic (MS LifeCam HD) - which had excellent audio quality on my desktop back in Ubuntu 10.04 when I use to use it. Same problem occurs! Too much noise... the audio quality is better, but there's just too much background "white" noise.